# 10x Single-cell RNA-Seq - Updating gene symbol with latest ensembl release - Ensembl IDs missing

Tags: scrnaseq, gene, ensembl

I am trying to update the gene symbols provided by the [10x human precompiled reference (2020-A)](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/downloads/latest), using the mapping Ensembl ID to gene symbol provided in release 102.

However, I found out that 56 of the Ensembl IDs (which I presumed to be stable) are not present in the latest release. See the attached image.

[image: table of missing ensembl ids]

See, for example, gene OCLM (ENSG00000262180) which seems to have a retired identifier:

[image: OCLM]

Is there a way to automatically filter or correct these identifiers, or should it be done manually? What is the most correct approach to take in this case (e.g., ignore them)?

#### Update

All but one are associated with deprecated identifiers, e.g., [ENSG00000262180](https://uswest.ensembl.org/Multi/Search/Results?q=ENSG00000262180)

The only one with 3 currently mapped identifiers is [ENSG00000183791](https://uswest.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Idhistory?g=ENSG00000183791).

Is it correct at this point to filter them out because associated with deprecated identifiers? What about the one with currently mapped identifiers?